# Calling `:ls` second time in Vim requires first clearing the commands

Tags: vim

If I open multiple files like so

```
vi *.js
```

and switch to, for example, buffer 9 via `:ls`, then type `:`, there is already a command like `.,.+8` Is this how vim is supposed to behave?

Comment: Can you tell exactly what are your keystrokes? This sounds strange to me.

Comment: I type `:ls` and it shows all the active buffers, then I type the number of the buffer I want to go to (is this the correct way to move between buffers?) then I type `:`

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I don't think it's a correct way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like what you're doing is pressing 9 to try and choose the buffer from `:ls`'s display.  `:ls` doesn't let you select a buffer.  It's just a list of the current, listed buffers in Vim.  However `9:` starts commandline mode with a range that specifies "9 lines, starting from the current line".

There are multiple ways you can switch to the buffer with the specified number.  E.g., to switch to buffer 9 you can

- In normal mode, press <kbd>9</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>^</kbd> (depending on the keyboard layout, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd> instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>^</kbd>)
- In commandline mode, `:9b` will change to buffer 9.

You can also specify a unique sub-string of the buffer's filename to the `:b` command to switch to the buffer that matches that sub-string.  So if you have `foo.c` and `bar.c` open, `:b f` would switch to `foo.c`.

Comment: vim is so awesome, I can't believe I have been using gedit all this time. I can use regular expressions `:b foo*fight*rs_*concert*.txt`

Comment: +1 to question and answer for inadvertently introducing me to `{count}:`

Answer (score 2):

To switch the buffer you need to `:b 9`.

Comment: I just figured it out too. I was doing `:bn 9`

Comment: `:bn 9` is good for moving to buffer 10  from buffer one (that is 9 buffers ahead)